# XSLT2 case insensitive regex

Tags: xslt

Good Day!

This is the first time I've posted a question here so please bear with me.

I'm having a problem in how to make match to a case insensitive I tried to add flag but not sure if that's the proper place insert flag because still my code seems not case insensitive.

Thank you in advance for sharing your idea on how I could solve this problem.

--elmer

I made edits to this post to add more codes I've made and sample of source XML file for any one want to make a test.

Base on the list of index entries I need to search every item from source XML to search and must be case insensitive. Like for example if will search the word "Abbreviation" all word "Abbreviation(s) or abbreviation(s)" must have anchor element beside on the word Abbreviation or abbreviation.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
xmlns:ati="http://www.asiatype.com/Functions" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- create variable for EALL_Index-->
<xsl:variable name="index" as="element() +">
    <xsl:for-each select="for $doc in document('EALL_Index_test.xml') return $doc/descendant::item">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(normalize-space(text()[1]))" order="descending"/>
        <list>
            <entry>
                <xsl:variable name="itemString">
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="text()[1]" regex="(\[)|(\])|(\()|(\))">
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                            <xsl:value-of select="replace(regex-group(1),'\[','\\[')"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="replace(regex-group(2),'\]','\\]')"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="replace(regex-group(3),'\(','\\(')"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="replace(regex-group(4),'\)','\\)')"/>
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($itemString)"/>
            </entry>
            <xsl:for-each select="link">
                <link target="{@targets}" id="{@n}">
                </link>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </list>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::*[self::simplearticle or self::complexarticle]]">
    <xsl:variable name="id" as="xs:string" select="current()/ancestor::*[self::simplearticle or self::complexarticle]/@id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="srchString" as="xs:string" select="."/>
     <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="some $term in $index[link/@target=$id]/entry satisfies matches($srchString, concat('(^|\W)(',$term, '[s]?)($|\W)'))">
             <xsl:message select="concat('(^|\W)(',string-join($index[link/@target=$id]/entry, '[s]?|'), ')($|\W)')"/>
             <xsl:analyze-string select="$srchString" regex="{concat('(^|\W)(',string-join($index[link/@target=$id]/entry, '[s]?|'), ')($|\W)')}">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$index[matches(regex-group(2), concat('(^|\W)(',entry, '[s]?)($|\W)'))]/link[@target=$id]">
                        <xsl:if test="matches($srchString, concat('(^|\W)(',entry, '[s]?)($|\W)'))">
                            <anchor target="{@target}" id="{@id}"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
         </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:sequence select="."/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Source XML for index entries:

```
<div2 id="EALL-index">
<head>EALL3 Index</head>
<art><simplearticle id="SIM-INDEX" entry="" volume="" page="">
<pseudoarticle>
<articleentry><mainentry>Index of Terms</mainentry></articleentry></pseudoarticle><list>
<item>Abbreviation <link type="eall" targets="SIM-0002" n="idx-abbreviation-01">Abbreviations</link>, <link type="eall" targets="SIM-0021" n="idx-abbreviation-02">Compounds</link>, <link type="eall" targets="COM-vol3-0192" n="idx-abbreviation-03">Lexicography: Monolingual Dictionaries</link>, <link type="eall" targets="COM-vol3-0276" n="idx-abbreviation-04">Punctuation</link></item>
</list></simplearticle></art></div2>
```

Source XML for search:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<art>
<simplearticle id="SIM-0002" entry="Abbreviations" volume="1" page="1:1a" sortcode="abbreviations">
<pseudoarticle>
<articleentry>
<mainentry>Abbreviations</mainentry>
</articleentry>
<p>Generally speaking, there are four main categories of abbreviations encountered in Arabic texts:</p>
<p>
<list>
<label>i.</label>
<item>i. Suspensions: abbreviation by truncation of the letters at the end of the word, e.g.&#160;&#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1589;&#1600; = <hi rend="italic">al-mu&#7779;annif</hi>. Perhaps the most interesting here is the case of suspensions that look like, or were considered by some to be, numerals. To this category belong the signs that resemble the numerals &#1778; and &#1635;, but which may represent the unpointed <hi rend="italic">t&#257;&#702;</hi> and <hi rend="italic">&#353;&#299;n</hi> (for <hi rend="italic">tam&#257;m</hi> and <hi rend="italic">&#353;ar&#7717;</hi>) when used in conjunction with marginal glosses.</item>
<label>ii.</label>
<item>ii. Contractions: abbreviating by means of omitting some letters in the middle of the word, but not the beginning or the ending, e.g. &#1602;&#1607; (<hi rend="italic">qawlu-hu</hi>).</item>
<label>iii.</label>
<item>iii. Sigla: using one letter to represent the whole word, e.g. &#1605; (<hi rend="italic">matn</hi>).</item>
<label>iv.</label>
<item>iv. Abbreviation symbols: symbols in the form of logographs used for whole words. A typical abbreviation symbol is the horizontal stroke (sometimes hooked at the end) which represents the word <hi rend="italic">sana</hi> &#8216;year&#8217;. Another example is the &#8216;two teeth stroke&#8217; (which looks like two unpointed <hi rend="italic">b&#257;</hi>'s), which represents the word &#1602;&#1601; &#8216;stop&#8217;, or the suspension &#1601;&#1578;&#1600; (for <hi rend="italic">fa-ta&#702;ammal-hu/h&#257;</hi> &#8216;reflect on it&#8217;), used in manuscripts for notabilia or side-heads.</item>
</list>
</p>
<p>Closely connected with these abbreviations is a contraction of a group of words into one &#8216;portmanteau&#8217; word (<hi rend="italic">na&#7717;t</hi>; <xref target="SIM-0021">compounds</xref>), for instance <hi rend="italic">basmala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">bi-sm All&#257;h</hi>) <hi rend="italic">&#7717;amdala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">al-&#7717;amdu li-ll&#257;h</hi>) and <hi rend="italic">&#7779;alwala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">&#7779;all&#257; ll&#257;h &#703;alayhi</hi>). To all intents and purposes, the word <hi rend="italic">na&#7717;t</hi> corresponds to an acronym, i.e. a word formed from the abbreviation of, in most cases, the initial letters of each word in the construct. Most of these constructs are textual and pious formulae. Apart from <hi rend="italic">basmala, &#7717;amdala</hi>, and <hi rend="italic">&#7779;alwala</hi>, we encounter <hi rend="italic">&#7789;albaqa</hi> (<hi rend="italic">&#7789;&#257;la ll&#257;h baq&#257;&#702;a-hu</hi>), <hi rend="italic">&#7717;awqala</hi> or <hi rend="italic">&#7717;awlaqa</hi> (<hi rend="italic">l&#257; &#7717;awla wa-l&#257; quwwata &#702;ill&#257; bi-ll&#257;h</hi>), <hi rend="italic">&#7779;al&#703;ama</hi> (a synonym of <hi rend="italic">&#7779;alwala</hi>), <hi rend="italic">&#7717;asbala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">&#7717;asbun&#257; all&#257;h</hi>), <hi rend="italic">ma&#353;&#702;ala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">m&#257; &#353;&#257;&#702;a ll&#257;h</hi>), <hi rend="italic">sab&#7717;ala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">sub&#7717;&#257;na ll&#257;h</hi>), and <hi rend="italic">&#7717;ay&#703;ala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">&#7717;ayya &#703;al&#257; &#7779;-&#7779;al&#257;t</hi>) (as-Samarr&#257;'&#299; 1987; Gacek 2001).</p>
<p>Abbreviations, especially contractions and sigla, may be (and often are) accompanied by a horizontal stroke (<hi rend="italic">tilde</hi>) placed above them. This mark may resemble the <hi rend="italic">madda</hi> but has nothing to do with the latter's function in Arabic script. Suspensions, on the other hand, were indicated by a long downward stroke, a mark that is very likely to have been borrowed from Greek and Latin paleographic practice.</p>
<p>The use of abbreviations was quite popular among Muslim scholars, although originally some of the abbreviations, such as those relating to the prayer for the Prophet (<hi rend="italic">ta&#7779;liya, &#7779;alwala</hi>), were disapproved of. In the manuscript age, abbreviations were extensively used, not only in the body of the text but also in marginalia, ownership statements, and in the primitive critical apparatus (Ben Cheneb 1920; Ma&#7717;f&#363;&#7827; 1964).</p>
<p>Medieval scholars could not always agree on the meaning of some of the abbreviations used in manuscripts. The letter &#1581;, for instance, which is used to separate one <hi rend="italic">&#702;isn&#257;d</hi> from another, was thought by some to stand for <hi rend="italic">&#7717;&#257;&#702;il</hi> or <hi rend="italic">&#7717;ayl&#363;la</hi> &#8216;separation&#8217; and by others for <hi rend="italic">&#7717;ad&#299;&#7791;</hi> and even <hi rend="italic">&#7779;a&#7717;&#7717;a</hi>. Some scholars even thought that the letter <hi rend="italic">&#7717;&#257;&#702;</hi> should be pointed (&#1582; &#8211; <hi rend="italic">x&#257;&#702; mu&#703;jama</hi>) to stand for <hi rend="italic">&#702;isn&#257;d &#702;&#257;xar</hi> &#8216;another <hi rend="italic">&#702;isn&#257;d</hi>&#8217;. The contemporary scholar may face a similar dilemma (see e.g. Ali&#269; 1976).</p>
<p>Abbreviations in manuscripts are often unpointed and appear sometimes in the form of word-symbols (logographs). Here, the context, whether textual or geographical, is of great importance. Thus, for instance, what appears to be the letter &#1591; may in fact be a &#1592;, and what appears to be an <hi rend="italic">&#703;ayn</hi> or <hi rend="italic">ayn</hi>, in its initial (&#1593;&#1600;) or isolated form (&#1593;), may actually be an unpointed <hi rend="italic">n&#363;n</hi> or <hi rend="italic">x&#257;&#702;</hi> (for <hi rend="italic">nusxa &#702;uxr&#257;</hi> &#8216;another copy&#8217;). Similarly, the same word or abbreviation can have two different functions and/or meanings. For example, the words <hi rend="italic">&#7717;&#257;&#353;iya</hi> and <hi rend="italic">f&#257;&#702;ida</hi> can stand for a gloss or a side-head (&#8216;nota bene&#8217;), while the &#1589; or &#1589;&#1600; can be an abbreviation of <hi rend="italic">&#7779;a&#7717;&#7717;a</hi> (when used for an omission/ insertion or evident correction) or <hi rend="italic">&#702;a&#7779;l</hi> (the body of the text), or it can stand for <hi rend="italic">&#7693;abba</hi> &#8216;door-bolt&#8217;, a mark indicating an uncertain reading and having, for all intents and purposes, the function of a question mark or &#8216;sic&#8217;. Also, the abbreviation &#1606; may stand for <hi rend="italic">bay&#257;n</hi> &#8216;explanation&#8217; or <hi rend="italic">nusxa &#702;uxr&#257;</hi>; the latter is often found in manuscripts of Persian/ Indian provenance.</p>
<p>The earliest use of abbreviations in the Arabic language is probably connected with its orthography and possibly the &#8216;mysterious letters&#8217; (<hi rend="italic">al-&#7717;ur&#363;f al-muqa&#7789;&#7789;a&#703;a</hi>) at the beginning of some chapters of the <hi rend="italic">Qur&#702;&#257;n</hi> (Bellamy 1973). In terms of orthography, for instance, the initial form of <hi rend="italic">j&#299;m</hi> (&#1580;&#1600;) or <hi rend="italic">m&#299;m</hi> (&#1605;&#1600;) was regarded by some scholars as an abbreviation of <hi rend="italic">jazma</hi>. Furthermore, the unpointed initial form of <hi rend="italic">&#353;&#299;n</hi> (&#1587;&#1600;) was used for <hi rend="italic">ta&#353;d&#299;d</hi> (or <hi rend="italic">&#353;adda</hi>), and the initial form of <hi rend="italic">&#7779;&#257;d</hi> (&#1589;&#1600;) was thought to represent <hi rend="italic">wa&#7779;la</hi> (or <hi rend="italic">&#7779;ila</hi>) (Wright 1967:13&#8211;14, 19; Gacek 2001:23).</p>
<p>Most of the abbreviations are found in the body of the text. They were introduced in order to speed up the process of transcription and their usage varied according to the subject or type of a given work. Abbreviations can be found in almost all types of works, but especially in compositions on the recitation of the <hi rend="italic">Qur&#702;&#257;n</hi>, compilation and criticism of <hi rend="italic">&#7716;ad&#299;&#7791;</hi>, philosophy, lexicography, poetry, genealogy, biography, and astronomy. The lists of these are often included in prefaces and frequently concern either the names of authors or titles of compositions. In addition, we find didactic poems that were composed specifically in order to help memorize given sets of abbreviations (see, e.g., &#703;Alaw&#257;n 1972). They are especially common in works on <hi rend="italic">&#7716;ad&#299;&#7791;</hi> and jurisprudence (both Sunni and Shi&#703;i) (al-M&#257;maq&#257;n&#299; 1992; a&#7827;-Zufayr&#299; 2002), and although some abbreviations were standardized, most were specific to a given work. Among the commonly used abbreviations for major <hi rend="italic">&#7716;ad&#299;&#7789;</hi> compilations are: &#1582; (al-Bux&#257;r&#299;), &#1605; (Muslim or M&#257;lik), &#1583; (&#702;Ab&#363; D&#257;&#702;&#363;d), &#1578; (at-Tirmi&#7695;&#299;), &#1603; (M&#257;lik), &#1607; (&#702;Ab&#363; &#7694;arr or Ibn M&#257;ja), &#1606; or &#1587; (an-Nas&#257;&#702;&#299;), and the like (Gacek 1989:56).</p>
</pseudoarticle>
</simplearticle>
</art>
```

Sample output:

```
<art>
<simplearticle id="SIM-0002" entry="Abbreviations" volume="1" sortcode="abbreviations" page="1:1a">
    <pseudoarticle>
        <articleentry>
            <mainentry><anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>Abbreviations</mainentry>
        </articleentry>
        <p>Generally speaking, there are four main categories of <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations encountered in Arabic texts:</p>
        <p>
            <list type="simple" TEIform="list">
                <label TEIform="label">i.</label>
                <item TEIform="item">i. Suspensions: <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviation by truncation of the letters at the end of the word, e.g. المصـ = <hi rend="italic">al-muṣannif</hi>. Perhaps the most interesting here is the case of suspensions that look like, or were considered by some to be, numerals. To this category belong the signs that resemble the numerals ۲ and ٣, but which may represent the unpointed <hi rend="italic">tāʾ</hi> and <hi rend="italic">šīn</hi> (for <hi rend="italic">tamām</hi> and <hi rend="italic">šarḥ</hi>) when used in conjunction with marginal glosses.</item>
                <label TEIform="label">ii.</label>
                <item TEIform="item">ii. Contractions: abbreviating by means of omitting some letters in the middle of the word, but not the beginning or the ending, e.g. قه (<hi rend="italic">qawlu-hu</hi>).</item>
                <label TEIform="label">iii.</label>
                <item TEIform="item">iii. Sigla: using one letter to represent the whole word, e.g. م (<hi rend="italic">matn</hi>).</item>
                <label TEIform="label">iv.</label>
                <item TEIform="item">iv. Abbreviation symbols: symbols in the form of logographs used for whole words. A typical <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviation symbol is the horizontal stroke (sometimes hooked at the end) which represents the word <hi rend="italic">sana</hi> ‘year’. Another example is the ‘two teeth stroke’ (which looks like two unpointed <hi rend="italic">bā</hi>'s), which represents the word قف ‘stop’, or the suspension فتـ (for <hi rend="italic">fa-taʾammal-hu/hā</hi> ‘reflect on it’), used in manuscripts for notabilia or side-heads.</item>
            </list>
        </p>
        <p>Closely connected with these <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations is a contraction of a group of words into one ‘portmanteau’ word (<hi rend="italic">naḥt</hi>; <xref target="SIM-0021">compounds</xref>), for instance <hi rend="italic">basmala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">bi-sm Allāh</hi>) <hi rend="italic">ḥamdala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">al-ḥamdu li-llāh</hi>) and <hi rend="italic">ṣalwala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">ṣallā llāh ʿalayhi</hi>). To all intents and purposes, the word <hi rend="italic">naḥt</hi> corresponds to an <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-acronym-01"/>acronym, i.e. a word formed from the <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviation of, in most cases, the initial letters of each word in the construct. Most of these constructs are textual and pious formulae. Apart from <hi rend="italic">basmala, ḥamdala</hi>, and <hi rend="italic">ṣalwala</hi>, we encounter <hi rend="italic">ṭalbaqa</hi> (<hi rend="italic">ṭāla llāh baqāʾa-hu</hi>), <hi rend="italic">ḥawqala</hi> or <hi rend="italic">ḥawlaqa</hi> (<hi rend="italic">lā ḥawla wa-lā quwwata ʾillā bi-llāh</hi>), <hi rend="italic">ṣalʿama</hi> (a synonym of <hi rend="italic">ṣalwala</hi>), <hi rend="italic">ḥasbala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">ḥasbunā allāh</hi>), <hi rend="italic">mašʾala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">mā šāʾa llāh</hi>), <hi rend="italic">sabḥala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">subḥāna llāh</hi>), and <hi rend="italic">ḥayʿala</hi> (<hi rend="italic">ḥayya ʿalā ṣ-ṣalāt</hi>) (as-Samarrā'ī 1987; Gacek 2001).</p>
        <p><anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>Abbreviations, especially contractions and sigla, may be (and often are) accompanied by a horizontal stroke (<hi rend="italic">tilde</hi>) placed above them. This mark may resemble the <hi rend="italic">madda</hi> but has nothing to do with the latter's function in Arabic script. Suspensions, on the other hand, were indicated by a long downward stroke, a mark that is very likely to have been borrowed from Greek and Latin paleographic practice.</p>
        <p>The use of <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations was quite popular among Muslim scholars, although originally some of the <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations, such as those relating to the prayer for the Prophet (<hi rend="italic">taṣliya, ṣalwala</hi>), were disapproved of. In the manuscript age, <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations were extensively used, not only in the body of the text but also in marginalia, ownership statements, and in the primitive critical apparatus (Ben Cheneb 1920; Maḥfūẓ 1964).</p>
        <p>Medieval scholars could not always agree on the meaning of some of the <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations used in manuscripts. The letter ح, for instance, which is used to separate one <hi rend="italic">ʾisnād</hi> from another, was thought by some to stand for <hi rend="italic">ḥāʾil</hi> or <hi rend="italic">ḥaylūla</hi> ‘separation’ and by others for <hi rend="italic">ḥadīṯ</hi> and even <hi rend="italic">ṣaḥḥa</hi>. Some scholars even thought that the letter <hi rend="italic">ḥāʾ</hi> should be pointed (خ – <hi rend="italic">xāʾ muʿjama</hi>) to stand for <hi rend="italic">ʾisnād ʾāxar</hi> ‘another <hi rend="italic">ʾisnād</hi>’. The contemporary scholar may face a similar dilemma (see e.g. Alič 1976).</p>
        <p><anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>Abbreviations in manuscripts are often unpointed and appear sometimes in the form of word-symbols (logographs). Here, the context, whether textual or geographical, is of great importance. Thus, for instance, what appears to be the letter ط may in fact be a ظ, and what appears to be an <hi rend="italic">ʿayn</hi> or <hi rend="italic">ayn</hi>, in its initial (عـ) or isolated form (ع), may actually be an unpointed <hi rend="italic">nūn</hi> or <hi rend="italic">xāʾ</hi> (for <hi rend="italic">nusxa ʾuxrā</hi> ‘another copy’). Similarly, the same word or <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviation can have two different functions and/or meanings. For example, the words <hi rend="italic">ḥāšiya</hi> and <hi rend="italic">fāʾida</hi> can stand for a gloss or a side-head (‘nota bene’), while the ص or صـ can be an <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviation of <hi rend="italic">ṣaḥḥa</hi> (when used for an omission/ insertion or evident correction) or <hi rend="italic">ʾaṣl</hi> (the body of the text), or it can stand for <hi rend="italic">ḍabba</hi> ‘door-bolt’, a mark indicating an uncertain reading and having, for all intents and purposes, the function of a question mark or ‘sic’. Also, the <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviation ن may stand for <hi rend="italic">bayān</hi> ‘explanation’ or <hi rend="italic">nusxa ʾuxrā</hi>; the latter is often found in manuscripts of Persian/ Indian provenance.</p>
        <p>The earliest use of <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations in the Arabic language is probably connected with its orthography and possibly the ‘mysterious letters’ (<hi rend="italic">al-ḥurūf al-muqaṭṭaʿa</hi>) at the beginning of some chapters of the <hi rend="italic">Qurʾān</hi> (Bellamy 1973). In terms of orthography, for instance, the initial form of <hi rend="italic">jīm</hi> (جـ) or <hi rend="italic">mīm</hi> (مـ) was regarded by some scholars as an <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviation of <hi rend="italic">jazma</hi>. Furthermore, the unpointed initial form of <hi rend="italic">šīn</hi> (سـ) was used for <hi rend="italic">tašdīd</hi> (or <hi rend="italic">šadda</hi>), and the initial form of <hi rend="italic">ṣād</hi> (صـ) was thought to represent <hi rend="italic">waṣla</hi> (or <hi rend="italic">ṣila</hi>) (Wright 1967:13–14, 19; Gacek 2001:23).</p>
        <p>Most of the <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations are found in the body of the text. They were introduced in order to speed up the process of transcription and their usage varied according to the subject or type of a given work. Abbreviations can be found in almost all types of works, but especially in compositions on the recitation of the <hi rend="italic">Qurʾān</hi>, compilation and criticism of <hi rend="italic">Ḥadīṯ</hi>, philosophy, lexicography, poetry, genealogy, biography, and astronomy. The lists of these are often included in prefaces and frequently concern either the names of authors or titles of compositions. In addition, we find didactic poems that were composed specifically in order to help memorize given sets of <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations (see, e.g., ʿAlawān 1972). They are especially common in works on <hi rend="italic">Ḥadīṯ</hi> and jurisprudence (both Sunni and Shiʿi) (al-Māmaqānī 1992; aẓ-Zufayrī 2002), and although some <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations were standardized, most were specific to a given work. Among the commonly used <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations for major <hi rend="italic">Ḥadīṭ</hi> compilations are: خ (al-Buxārī), م (Muslim or Mālik), د (ʾAbū Dāʾūd), ت (at-Tirmiḏī), ك (Mālik), ه (ʾAbū Ḏarr or Ibn Māja), ن or س (an-Nasāʾī), and the like (Gacek 1989:56).</p>
        <p>Specific to <hi rend="italic">Ḥadīṯ</hi> literature are other <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations connected with the frequent repetitions of such expressions as <hi rend="italic">ḥaddaṯ anā, ʾaxbaranā</hi>, and <hi rend="italic">ʾanbaʾanā</hi>, which were commonly abbreviated as: دثنا ,ثنا ,نا (<hi rend="italic">ḥaddaṯ anā</hi>); ابنا ,ارنا ,انا (<hi rend="italic">ʾaxbaranā</hi>); ق ثنا ,قثنا (<hi rend="italic">qāla ḥaddaṯ anā</hi>). The transition from one <hi rend="italic">ʾisnād</hi> to another, as mentioned above, was marked with ح (<hi rend="italic">ḥāʾil, taḥwīl, ḥaylula, ḥadīṯ</hi> or <hi rend="italic">ṣaḥḥa</hi>) (Gacek 1989:56), and for the evaluation of <hi rend="italic">ḥadīṯ</hi>s the following <anchor target="SIM-0002" id="idx-abbreviation-01"/>abbreviations were used:ض (<hi rend="italic">ḍaʿīf</hi>), صح (<hi rend="italic">ṣaḥīḥ</hi>), ح (<hi rend="italic">ḥasan</hi>); م (<hi rend="italic">majhūl</hi>), مو (<hi rend="italic">muwāfiq</hi> or <hi rend="italic">mawqūf</hi>), قف (<hi rend="italic">mawqūf</hi>); ق (<hi rend="italic">muwaṭṭaq</hi> or <hi rend="italic">muttafaq ʿalayhi</hi>), ل (<hi rend="italic">mursal</hi>) (e.g. Gacek 1985:xiv, 96).</p>
    </pseudoarticle>
</simplearticle>
```

Comment: It can't hurt to show what you try to achieve (supply input and expected output). I have the feeling it can be done in a much simpler and intuitive way.

Comment: As per your request I made edits to my post with sample xml and sample output. Hope it make me clear now. thanks again.

Comment: There's far more code here than is needed to illustrate the problem, can't you explain it more concisely? In XPath functions such as replace() and matches(), there is a "flags" argument which you can set to "i" for case-independent matching. You can't include the flag within the regex itself.

Comment: @ElmerBanate it looks as if you wish to add an anchor element to mainentry, and add the same anchor element to all occurrences of the mainentry value in the rest of the file, disregarding case. Is that correct?

Comment: @Maestro13: yes that's correct... actually it's not the mainentry, it must add an anchor if it can find that word within any descendant::text() of simplearticle or complexarticle.

Comment: @MichaelKay: do you have any idea how I could make a regex that is case insensitive sorry but I'm not good in regex. Thanks!

Comment: @ElmerBanate As far as I know that is done by appending /i. see [regex modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

Comment: If you're using matches(), then matches($x, $regex, 'i') does a case-insensitive match. Like I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My other answer is one that does not use the replace function - which causes an incomplete result because occurrences of "abbreviations," are not replaced.
So I tried another approach including making use of the "i" flag as suggested by Michael; unluckily this is more complex because it requires serialization to string of the anchor element. See below.
Note: this solution has a slight flaw too: case is not preserved for occurrences like "Abbreviations".
Also, a slight improvement to the serialize template will lead to `< anchor .../>` instead of `< anchor ...>< /anchor>`

See **EDITED** below for a version where both issues have been solved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:f="data:f"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="f xs">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="searchString" select="//simplearticle/@sortcode"/>
    <xsl:variable name="anchor">
        <xsl:element name="anchor">
            <xsl:attribute name="target" select="//simplearticle/@id"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="id" select="concat('idx-', $searchString,'-01')"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="main"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="main">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="main"/>
        </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="main">
        <!--<xsl:variable name="replacement" select="concat(f:serialize($anchor), $searchString)"/>-->
        <xsl:variable name="anchorAdd" select="f:serialize($anchor)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="replacement">
            <xsl:value-of select="$anchorAdd"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$searchString"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $searchString, $replacement, 'i')"  disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="serialize">
        <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize" select="@*"/> 
        <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize"/> 
        <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="serialize">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="serialize">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>="<xsl:value-of select="."/>"
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="f:serialize">
        <xsl:param name="xml"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize" select="$xml"/> 
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDITED**

Explanation:
(1) made use of backreference $0 for string to be replaced
(2) still had to use the replacement variable although that seems a little odd; reason is an error message when using $anchorAdd directly
(3) serialization: test on non-emptiness of (text) node - in that case /> instead of applying templates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:f="data:f"
        exclude-result-prefixes="f">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="searchString" select="lower-case(//simplearticle/@sortcode)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="anchor">
        <xsl:element name="anchor">
            <xsl:attribute name="target" select="//simplearticle/@id"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="id" select="concat('idx-', $searchString,'-01')"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="main"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="main">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="main"/>
        </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="main">
        <xsl:variable name="anchorAdd" select="f:serialize($anchor)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="replacement">
            <xsl:value-of select="$anchorAdd"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $searchString, concat($replacement, '$0'), 'i')"  disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="serialize">
        <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize" select="@*"/> 
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not (string(.))">
                <xsl:text>/&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize"/> 
                <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text> 
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="serialize">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="serialize">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>="<xsl:value-of select="."/>"<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="f:serialize">
        <xsl:param name="xml"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize" select="$xml"/> 
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from details (such as a different item list and selection of where to construct the anchor from, plus changes when looping over multiple art elements), the below should get you going again (no need for regex, just using appropriate functions). I did not yet replace occurrences of abbreviation in the text. Or was that a mistake on your behalf? Should "abbreviation" be handled too, next to "abbreviations"? Then how decide to do that? For instance take of "s" of searchString and handle that word too?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:f="data:f"
        exclude-result-prefixes="f">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="searchString" select="//simplearticle/@sortcode"/>
    <xsl:variable name="anchor">
        <xsl:element name="anchor">
            <xsl:attribute name="target" select="//simplearticle/@id"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="id" select="concat('idx-', $searchString,'-01')"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:call-template name="checkWord">
            <xsl:with-param name="splitText" select="tokenize(., ' ')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="checkWord">
        <xsl:param name="splitText"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$splitText">
            <xsl:if test="lower-case(.) = $searchString">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$anchor"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you for helping me solving this problem... but sorry if I made you confuse...

Comment: @ElmerBanate thank me by accepting my answer - but only when you like it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to solve my problem so I've posted here the working XSLT.

First I've add 'i' to my match functions:

when

```
test="some $term in $index[link/@target=$id]/entry satisfies matches($srchString, concat('(^|\W)(',$term, '[s]?)($|\W)'),'i');
```

for-each `select="$index[matches(regex-group(2), concat('(^|\W)(',entry, '[s]?)($|\W)'),'i')]/link[@target=$id]`

```
if test="matches($srchString, concat('(^|\W)(',entry, '[s]?)($|\W)'),'i')

then add regex to match the lowercase word(s) by adding lower-case(string-join($index[link/@target=$id]/entry, '[s]?|')) in to the analyze-string.

analyze-string select="$srchString" regex="{concat('(^|\W)(',lower-case(string-join($index[link/@target=$id]/entry, '[s]?|')), '[s]?|', string-join($index[link/@target=$id]/entry, '[s]?|'), ')($|\W)')}"
```

using this regex I was able to get lower case "abbreviation" and "Abbreviation" with initial caps.

```
(^|\W)(abbreviation[s]?|acronym[s]?|Abbreviation[s]?|acronym)($|\W)
```

Special thanks to **Michael Kay** and **Maestro13**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:ati="http://www.asiatype.com/Functions" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="Entries">
        <xsl:for-each select="for $doc in collection(iri-to-uri(concat('original-eall-xml/', '?select=*.xml'))) return $doc/descendant::art/*">
            <list>
                <entry>
                    <xsl:value-of select=".//mainentry"/>
                </entry>
                <id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
                </id>
                <page>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@page"/>
                </page>
            </list>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="art/*">
        <xsl:variable name="myId">
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(@id,' ')[1]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="myStrings" select="//text()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="myEntry" select="descendant::mainentry/text()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @page"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$Entries//entry[.=$myEntry] and $Entries//entry[.=$myEntry]/following-sibling::id[.=$myId]">
                    <xsl:attribute name="page"><xsl:value-of select="$Entries//entry[.=$myEntry]/following-sibling::page"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="page">0</xsl:attribute>
                    <!--<xsl:message select="concat('mainentry: &quot;', $myEntry, '&quot; - volume: &quot;', @volume, '&quot; - id: &quot;',$myId, '&quot;')"/>-->
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>    

    <!-- create variable for EALL_Index-->
    <xsl:variable name="index" as="element() +">
        <xsl:for-each select="for $doc in document('EALL_Index_test.xml') return $doc/descendant::item">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(normalize-space(text()[1]))" order="descending"/>
            <list>
                <entry>
                    <xsl:variable name="itemString">
                        <xsl:analyze-string select="text()[1]" regex="(\[)|(\])|(\()|(\))">
                            <xsl:matching-substring>
                                <xsl:value-of select="replace(regex-group(1),'\[','\\[')"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="replace(regex-group(2),'\]','\\]')"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="replace(regex-group(3),'\(','\\(')"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="replace(regex-group(4),'\)','\\)')"/>
                            </xsl:matching-substring>
                            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        </xsl:analyze-string>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($itemString)"/>
                </entry>
                <xsl:for-each select="link">
                    <link target="{@targets}" id="{@n}">
                    </link>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </list>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::*[self::simplearticle or self::complexarticle]]">
        <xsl:variable name="id" as="xs:string" select="current()/ancestor::*[self::simplearticle or self::complexarticle]/@id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="srchString" as="xs:string" select="."/>
         <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="some $term in $index[link/@target=$id]/entry satisfies matches($srchString, concat('(^|\W)(',$term, '[s]?)($|\W)'),'i')">
                 <xsl:message select="concat('(^|\W)(',lower-case(string-join($index[link/@target=$id]/entry, '[s]?|')), '[s]?|', string-join($index[link/@target=$id]/entry, '[s]?|'), ')($|\W)')"/>
                 <xsl:analyze-string select="$srchString" regex="{concat('(^|\W)(',lower-case(string-join($index[link/@target=$id]/entry, '[s]?|')), '[s]?|', string-join($index[link/@target=$id]/entry, '[s]?|'), ')($|\W)')}">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$index[matches(regex-group(2), concat('(^|\W)(',entry, '[s]?)($|\W)'),'i')]/link[@target=$id]">
                            <xsl:if test="matches($srchString, concat('(^|\W)(',entry, '[s]?)($|\W)'),'i')">
                                <anchor target="{@target}" id="{@id}"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
             </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:sequence select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```